# How to center table data

Tags: html, css, react-bootstrap

[image]

For this particular table, how do I center resource ID on the left column so it is aligned in the center of the Resource ID column (where the horizontal line is on the right side)? The data is fetched from an API so left column will always contain only one resource ID but the right column can contains hundreds of policies.

Answer (score 1):

As the text is already centerd horizontally in your example, I think you want to vertically center the content. Therefore you may use `vertical-align` css property on the table cell(s) and position your content to the `middle`.

Note that `vertical-align` only applies to `inline`, `inline-block` and `table-cell` elements.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.v-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>left column</td>
    <td>right column</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3" class="v-middle">data</td>
    <td>row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```